# How to filter command line output in GUI?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I output the content of the command line to the text box of the interface, how to filter the content of the text box and only display the IPv4 address[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lwgp.png)

```
def runcommand():
p = threading.Thread(target=step)
p.setDaemon(True)
p.start()
cmd = cmdtextbox.get()
cmd_result = subprocess.run(cmd,shell=True,capture_output=True,text=True)
output = cmd_result.stdout
filter_function = filter(lambda w: 'IPv4 address',output)
outputtextbox.insert(END,output,filter_function)
outputlabel['text']='OUTPUT'
outputlabel.config(fg="green")
cmdtextbox['state'] ='normal'
runbtn['state'] = 'normal'
p.join()
progress.grid_remove()
```

Comment: You can match with a regular expression the output you desire. Check out https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.